# Cloud dns api auth without gcloud or any librares/clients?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

Is it possible to auth to cloud dns api without gcloud or libraries?
For example, for api call ManagedZones: list https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/reference/v1/managedZones/list

I just want to use key from .json file of early created Service account.

What request/url/headers should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, hence could you please provide more details. Are you trying to use API key as your method of authentication instead of the Google OAuth 2.0?

Comment: @SunnyJ. thanks for reply. Yes, I'm try API key at first, but getting:
"401 unauthorized. Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."
And then I found, that API key don't supported auth method for cloud dns API.
So, I'm looking for a simple auth method, using "Service account", but can't figure out, how to use it.

Comment: I have checked this. Currently is not possible to authenticate with a "Service Account". However you may submit this as a feature request using the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187241&template=1162816).

Answer (score 0):

Already found a solution in docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Service account must have a "DNS Administrator" role and associated with project.

The process described in "Preparing to make an authorized API call" on tab "HTTP/REST".

Libraries for generating JWT and debug it can be found at https://jwt.io/

Comment: This seems like a good workaround, however I would recommend submitting this as a feature request.